# vba - item not found in this collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I keep keep getting 
Run-time error '3265':

Item not found in this collection 
for rstAnswers("20GBRank") = irank while it works in other db.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function Update20BldgRank()
Dim db As Database
Dim rstAnswers As Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim irank As Integer
irank = 1
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rstAnswers = db.OpenRecordset("Top20Genbld13", dbOpenDynaset)
rstAnswers.MoveFirst
Do Until rstAnswers.EOF
rstAnswers.Edit
rstAnswers("20GBRank") = irank
rstAnswers.Update
rstAnswers.MoveNext
irank = irank + 1
Loop
rstAnswers.Close
Update20BldgRank = irank - 1
End Function
```

Comment: I've updated the code and here is image http://i.imgur.com/LEph4GP.png

Comment: rstAnswers("20GRank") is now rstAnswers("20GBRank")

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure field(column) **20GRank** exist in db where you are getting the error.

Comment: The column exist in the db.

Comment: Can you update the screenshot of table schema **Topld13** in your post.

Comment: here are the tables and queries that are being used http://i.imgur.com/LEph4GP.png

Comment: im having the same issue, my code is saying the field doesnt exist even though it does, although im using a variable since im looking through 140 fields.